# The background property of QWidget don't work. (already provided a paintEvent)

Tags: qt, qt4

I use style sheet to customize `myWidget` which subclass `QSpinBox`. Only the background property can't work.

I already provided a `paintEvent` for customizing `myWidget`, but it doesn't work.

stylesheet:

```
mySpinBox {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

code:

```
class mySpinBox : public QSpinBox {
Q_OBJECT
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
}

void mySpinBox::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter p(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
}
```

Comment: 1. How do you assign this stylesheet? 2. Show the code where you create an instance of mySpinBox.

Comment: @Ezee 1. `QApplication app; app.setStyleSheet(...);` 2. `mySpinBox *spinBox = new mySpinBox;`

Comment: Until now everything is correct and works for me. Probably the problem is in the other style sheet declarations. You can try replace all your style sheet lines with these three and see what's happen.

Comment: is [autoFillBackground](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop) set?

Comment: @ratchetfreak In `autoFillBackground` document, **Warning: Use this property with caution in conjunction with Qt Style Sheets. When a widget has a style sheet with a valid background or a border-image, this property is automatically disabled.** 
But I try set autoFillBackground true or false. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Ezee My style sheet only this 3 lines. but it's still not working.

Comment: So as I said the code you posted here is fully functional on my side. Anyway you must set parent for `spinBox` to avoid memory leaking. It would also help with styles if you have set it to a MainWindow. But setting a style sheet to the application works even if a widget has no a parent. If you create an empty project with this code you will be able to ensure that it does work or at least post a link to it here so I could compile your code and check it also.

Comment: `don't work`, `can't work`... can you just describe what happen as a result? Can you take a snapshot and attach the image? Btw can we have the full lines of the `app.setStyleSheet()`?